# How to secure my PHP webpage from unauthorized Users

Tags: php

I am new in PHP and facing a problem with security.
I use this to redirect unauthorized users if they not logged in.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

It is on every top of my page but when I log in and click my protected page it will redirect to login page instead of original/protected page open and my session variable is set on my login page how to include this session variable in my protected page from login page.

Comment: post your login page `code`

Answer (score 1):

If when, you log in, it sends you to login page, then `$_SESSION['user_id']` may not be set, or you aren't including session in your file, to check it, do:

`var_dump($_SESSION['user_id'])`

on the page, and temporally leave out the `header` if the var_dump returns NULL, it means, `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not set

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    // The user id variable is not set. Therefore, the user is most likely a guest.
    $_SESSION['user_id'] == 0;
}
if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 0)
{
    // The user does not have a user id set. We assume, therefore, that they are a guest.
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Also, in your login script, ensure that you are setting `$_SESSION['user_id']` to anything other than 0.